# Polling / Pushing from Socket

Tags: linux, sockets, can-bus

I want to write a android system server for socket can. Im currently designing this and wondered if there is any way to get informed if data on a Linux/POSIX socket is available without calling read() and poll the result any time.

Comment: Just curious, if have looked at this project: https://github.com/entropia/libsocket-can-java?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I really didn't find this Project before, but I'm going to implement it myself as expirience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this, among them i/o multiplexing, signal-drive i/o, and asynchronous i/o.

It's likely that for your purposes multiplexing will suffice and it is by far the easiest to implement and get right.  Investigate **[select](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm)**, **[poll](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm)** or **[epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll)**  There are an abundance of articles, references, and examples available and no shortage of questions/answers here to help you get started.  Most common programming languages have a mechanism to expose these services.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I used epoll now